# How change thread (priority) for WorkflowApplication

Tags: c#, multithreading, workflow, workflow-foundation

The `WorkflowApplication.Run()` method will always spin up a new thread to run the workflow on. How can this thread be influenced? Change the priority or completely replace the thread with your own?

Comment: What is the question behind the question, what is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: @PeterBons I want to be able set a lower thread priority for a group of worker processes. To free up resources for higher priority.

Comment: There is a general recommendation to avoid messing with thread-priorities. Part of the reason is that most threading models use the ThreadPool, and if you fail to reset the priority of the threadpool thread it can easily result in strange behavior. So have you carefully considered if this is really needed? Will your application handle the case where the background work never gets to run?